# Calling and connecting

Tags: twilio

I am trying to call two person at same time and want to join the calls. For example, call A and B, once one of them picks up say A , I want to play a message and connect the other person in this case B. So A and B communicates twilio is making the call and connect both of them. Is this possible?

Comment: Here are your answers : Yes, No. Maybe. What have you tried ?

Comment: Yeah, it would be useful to know what you've tried. Also, what language are you working with?

Comment: Check my answer, maybe this is what you're trying to do. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37979664/make-a-call-between-two-numbers-not-registered-in-twilio/37980736#37980736

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we are using PHP for this implementation, it would look something like this.

**Code to call person A:**

```
    <?php
    // Get the PHP helper library from twilio.com/docs/php/install
    require_once('/path/to/twilio-php/Services/Twilio.php'); // Loads the library

    // Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
    $sid = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"; 
    $token = "your_auth_token"; 
    $client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token);
    $person_a_phone = "+15555555555";
    $verified_twilio_number = "+14444444444";
    $person_b_phone = "+13333333333";
    $call = $client->account->calls->create($verified_twilio_number, $person_a_phone, "http://callback.php?person_b_phone=$person_b_phone", array());
```

**Code To Call person B (ie. callback.php):**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Response>
        <Play>http://url-to-play-your-message.com</Play>
        <Dial timeout="10" record="true"><?php echo $_REQUEST['person_b_phone'] ?></Dial>
    </Response>
```

References:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls