# How to record when Make a call between two numbers not registered in twilio

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php, twilio-click-to-call

I did when Make a call between two numbers not registered in Twilio using following link "[Make a call between two numbers not registered in twilio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37979664/make-a-call-between-two-numbers-not-registered-in-twilio)" in C#. But I need to record while pressing 1 during the call at any time.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi! What have you tried so far? I can try to help, but I can't write your whole solution for you.

Comment: As I mention above i created a new application with Twilio rest API  to make a call between to users.I know we have the option to record the conversation using RECORD attribute. But I need an option to start recording manually during a call.  For example, i want to talk to MR. John but i was not available instead of somebody pick the phone.At this point, i don't want to record the conversation.What i want is i have another button called Record along with call button.while click the record button i want to start record.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You cannot nest a [`<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather) within a [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial), so you can't interrupt a call between two people by pressing 1.

You could place your callers in a [`<Conference>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/conference) (in fact, according to that SO question you linked to, it looks like you might have already). Then you can use `<Dial>`'s [`hangupOnStar` attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial#attributes-hangup-on-star) to end the conference for the moderator and allow them to record the call.

You'd then need to direct the moderator into a new `<Conference>` with the [`record` attribute set to `record-from-start`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/conference#attributes-record). And then you'd need to [redirect the original caller](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/change-call-state) from their original conference to the conference that is being recorded.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: As mention above moderator (Twilio Number) use < Dial>'s hangupOnStar attribute to end the conference will the call of other two participants in this conference get cut?

Comment: The other participants would remain in the conference (unless you had set `endConferenceOnExit` to true for the moderator). You would need to redirect the other callers to the new conference that is being recorded though.

Comment: Hi philnash,

How to integration masking phone number for sending SMS.

Description:

I wnat to send sms shipper and shipper replay the SMS to drivers.But Shipper dpn't want to see the  courir number.But when the shipper replays  the sms the courier able to see it.

Comment: To do number masking, you need to use a Twilio number to receive the messages and send them on to the other party. [This article explains how you would achieve that](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223134067-How-users-can-send-text-messages-to-each-other-over-Twilio). You may also be interested in [Twilio Proxy](https://www.twilio.com/proxy) which can handle these relationships automatically. It is in preview though, so you need to [request access](https://www.twilio.com/proxy#request-access).

Comment: Let's keep this discussion on the other question. In the meantime, if this answer did help with your original question, please do mark it as correct so that others know.